# GroupBy statement to see latest subscription state

Tags: sql, database

I'm having a little trouble creating a SQL statement that will show these users latest subscription state. Here is sample data

```
subscription_id: abc
user_id: 123
product: ESPN
from_state: trial
to_state: new
transition_time: 2020-01-01:00:00:00:000

subscription_id: abc
user_id: 123
product: ESPN
from_state: new
to_state: canceled
transition_time: 2020-01-01:00:00:00:002

subscription_id: abc
user_id: 123
product: DISNEY
from_state: trial
to_state: new
transition_time: 2020-01-01:00:00:00:000

subscription_id: ab4
user_id: 123
product: ESPN
from_state: inactive
to_state: trial
transition_time: 2020-01-01:00:00:00:006

subscription_id: ab23
user_id: 126
product: ESPN
from_state: trial
to_state: new
transition_time: 2020-01-01:00:00:00:009
```

The subscription_id is a field that represents the product and plan type you select(EX: espn with 1 week subscription). The user_id is a unique field for every user. The product is the kind of product you'd be subscribing to (ex: Espn). From_state, to_state are the transitions this user has made (Ex: Trial to new). And the transition_time being the time this was made at.

Given this I'd like to create a query that only shows me user_id, product, and to_state for the LATEST state for my products and users. This query should return these four rows if ran on the example above:

```
user_id: 123
product: ESPN
to_state: canceled


user_id: 123
product: DISNEY
to_state: new


user_id: 123
product: ESPN
to_state: trial


user_id: 126
product: ESPN
to_state: new
```

Thanks

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by transition_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your table is named `source_data` you can try this:

```
SELECT x.product, x.user_id, x.to_state
FROM   source_data AS x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM   source_data AS y
         WHERE  y.user_id = x.user_id
         AND    y.product = x.product
         AND    y.transition_time > x.transition_time
       )
;
```

This should work in any ANSI-SQL compatible database.

---

Basically it takes your data table twice (each instance named `x` and `y`, respectivelly), then joins them together by the compound key {user_id, product}, and keeps only the rows where `x` has the highest `transition_time`.